# Camelot can't create new project

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to install and run the framework Camelot on Ubuntu 12.04. But from the error the problem seems to be sqlalchemy. I've installed camelot with:

`pip install camelot` and it installed without any problems. I've tried to upgrade both sqlalchemy and camelot but it throws an exception and won't work when I run:

`python -m camelot.bin.camelot_admin`

Some versions:

```
In [1]: import camelot

In [2]: camelot.__version__
Out[2]: '12.06.29'

In [3]: import sqlalchemy

In [4]: sqlalchemy.__version__
Out[4]: '0.8.0b2'
```

This is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/bin/camelot_admin.py", line 263, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/bin/camelot_admin.py", line 255, in main
    meta()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/bin/camelot_admin.py", line 243, in meta
    from camelot.bin.meta import launch_meta_camelot
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/bin/meta.py", line 34, in <module>
    from camelot.admin.application_admin import ApplicationAdmin
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/admin/application_admin.py", line 34, in <module>
    from camelot.admin.action import application_action, form_action, list_action
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/admin/action/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from application_action import ( ApplicationActionGuiContext,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/admin/action/application_action.py", line 31, in <module>
    from camelot.core.orm import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camelot/core/orm.py", line 48, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import ( declarative_base, 
ImportError: cannot import name _declarative_constructor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I downgraded to sqlalchemy 0.7.8 from 0.8 and cleaned up some previous installed files. Now it works great.

Comment: For future searchers: apparently _declarative_constructor (and probably a lot more) was moved from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative to sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.api sometime between 0.7.8 and 0.8, so you  just need to modify the import line.